# Cannot find resources for Metal iOS

Tags: ios, metal

I am trying to learn Metal for 3D development for iOS. I looked online and theres a couple of short articles that only cover the basics of Metal. Theres also a book "Metal by example", however the book does not go into much detail of Metal either. I also checked a similar question that was asked on stack overflow but the answers just lead me to the same articles. Does anyone know a good resource (book, video, or web tutorials) that can teach me the basics all the way to a expert level of metal?

Comment: I started a series about [Using MetalKit](http://mhorga.org) last month and it is based on the great `Metal by Example` book. My series plans to go into as much detail as possible but you might need to have patience for the next parts to be published in the coming weeks. There are not many `Metal` resources out there yet!

Comment: Thank you! Will definitely look into your tutorials. Also like how you did them in Swift. If you post this as answer, I will surely give you correct answer.

Comment: have you checked out WWDC? there should be resources from 2013 or 2014

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to get a comprehensive resource guide for Metal, as it's still in its infancy. There's a few stuff, but it doesn't feel like enough to make you actually good at this.

Here's what I'm suggesting: bite the bullet and learn a bit of OpenGL ES first. There are tonnes of tutorials online, as well as books. Just do a bit of it; enough to draw textured objects. But make sure you can understand the underlying concepts of those basics. After that, pick up a good book on general computer graphics concepts. A good one is Real Time Rendering (Möller, Haines, and Hoffman). This will build your knowledge of graphics as a science, and Metal will simply be a tool to realise these concepts. In order to realise them, the official Apple documentation and WWDC videos will then suffice.

There are a lot of common terminologies between Metal and OpenGL ES, which is why I'm recommending learning it first. They're all computer graphics anyways. So your goal should be learning computer graphics. Metal will be your tool for the job.

Answer (score 0):

Start with MetalKit, and by building something of consequence—like a camera app that processes video output using any of the Metal Performance Shaders:

```
@import UIKit;
@import AVFoundation;
@import CoreMedia;
#import <MetalKit/MetalKit.h>
#import <Metal/Metal.h>
#import <MetalPerformanceShaders/MetalPerformanceShaders.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <MTKViewDelegate, AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate>  {
    NSString *_displayName;
    NSString *serviceType;
}

@property (retain, nonatomic) SessionContainer *session;
@property (retain, nonatomic) AVCaptureSession *avSession;

@end;

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController () {
    MTKView *_metalView;

    id<MTLDevice> _device;
    id<MTLCommandQueue> _commandQueue;
    id<MTLTexture> _texture;

    CVMetalTextureCacheRef _textureCache;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) AVCaptureDevice *videoDevice;
@property (nonatomic) dispatch_queue_t sessionQueue;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice();
    _metalView = [[MTKView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    [_metalView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
    _metalView.device = _device;
    _metalView.delegate = self;
    _metalView.clearColor = MTLClearColorMake(1, 1, 1, 1);
    _metalView.colorPixelFormat = MTLPixelFormatBGRA8Unorm;
    _metalView.framebufferOnly = NO;
    _metalView.autoResizeDrawable = NO;

    CVMetalTextureCacheCreate(NULL, NULL, _device, NULL, &_textureCache);

    [self.view addSubview:_metalView];

    self.sessionQueue = dispatch_queue_create( "session queue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL );

    if ([self setupCamera]) {
        [_avSession startRunning];
    }
}

- (BOOL)setupCamera {
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    @try {
        NSError * error;

            _avSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
            [_avSession beginConfiguration];
            [_avSession setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480];

            // get list of devices; connect to front-facing camera
            self.videoDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
            if (self.videoDevice == nil) return FALSE;

            AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:self.videoDevice error:&error];
            [_avSession addInput:input];

            dispatch_queue_t sampleBufferQueue = dispatch_queue_create("CameraMulticaster", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);

            AVCaptureVideoDataOutput * dataOutput = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];
            [dataOutput setAlwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames:YES];
            [dataOutput setVideoSettings:@{(id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey: @(kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA)}];
            [dataOutput setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:sampleBufferQueue];

            [_avSession addOutput:dataOutput];
            [_avSession commitConfiguration]; 
    } @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"%s - %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, exception.description);
        return FALSE;
    } @finally {
        return TRUE;
    }

}

- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
{
    CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
    {
        size_t width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(pixelBuffer);
        size_t height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(pixelBuffer);

        CVMetalTextureRef texture = NULL;
        CVReturn status = CVMetalTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(kCFAllocatorDefault, _textureCache, pixelBuffer, NULL, MTLPixelFormatBGRA8Unorm, width, height, 0, &texture);
        if(status == kCVReturnSuccess)
        {
            _metalView.drawableSize = CGSizeMake(width, height);
            _texture = CVMetalTextureGetTexture(texture);
            _commandQueue = [_device newCommandQueue];
            CFRelease(texture);
        }
    }
}

- (void)drawInMTKView:(MTKView *)view {
    // creating command encoder
    if (_texture) {
        id<MTLCommandBuffer> commandBuffer = [_commandQueue commandBuffer];
        id<MTLTexture> drawingTexture = view.currentDrawable.texture;

        // set up and encode the filter
        MPSImageGaussianBlur *filter = [[MPSImageGaussianBlur alloc] initWithDevice:_device sigma:5];

        [filter encodeToCommandBuffer:commandBuffer sourceTexture:_texture destinationTexture:drawingTexture];

        // committing the drawing
        [commandBuffer presentDrawable:view.currentDrawable];
        [commandBuffer commit];
        _texture = nil;
    }
}

- (void)mtkView:(MTKView *)view drawableSizeWillChange:(CGSize)size {

}

@end
```